# Sort a list in C#

Tags: c#, .net, linq

How to sort a List in such a way item of list matching string comes first.
Suppose if i have

```
  "vishal pandey"
```

in string then item of list matching "vishal pandey" comes first then it should show result of item containing "vishal" and item containing "pandey"

**It is not possible for me bring data in that order from database**
Currently I am getting list like this

```
  var matchedProjects = (from project in unitOfWork.ProjectRepository.All()
                                   where project.IsActive
                                     && project is Project
                                     && (
                                           queryList.Contains(project.Name)
                                        || project.Name.StartsWith(query)
                                        || project.Name.Contains(query)
                                        || project.Name.EndsWith(query)
                                        || project.ProjectAddress.City.Name.StartsWith(query)
                                        || project.ProjectAddress.City.Name.Contains(query)
                                        || project.ProjectAddress.City.Name.EndsWith(query)
                                        || queryList.Contains(project.ProjectAddress.City.Name)
                                        || queryList.Contains(project.ProjectAddress.Address1)
                                        )
                                   select project as Project).Distinct().AsParallel().ToList();
```

-Thanks

Comment: what are your said "item" like ? a `List<string>` and `List<>` of custom object ? what field you want to compare ? elaborate more please

Comment: @Franck no its a list of object(Model)

Comment: you should implement a method that implement partially @Sergey solution within the `Project` class that will receive the query and check all properties you want and count the matches. Then you simply do a `var listOfProjectThatMatch = unitOfWork.ProjectRepository.All().ToList().Where(p=> p.GetMatchesQuantity("vishal pandey") > 0).ToList()` then with that list filtered out you can order using quantity of matches again or anything else you want to sort by

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Simplest (but not very efficient) solution is just applying lots of sorts to your items:

```
var keywords = "vishal pandey";
var items = new[] { "pandey", "other", "vishal", "vishal pandey" };

var query = items.OrderByDescending(i => i.Contains(keywords));

foreach (var keyword in keywords.Split())
    query = query.ThenByDescending(i => i.Contains(keyword));
```

Output:

```
vishal pandey
vishal
pandey
other
```

But if you have many keywords, or there is lot of items, custom comparer will be *much better* solution.

UPDATE1: If order of partial matches will not be important, you can use this simple solution suggested by  Frank:

```
var pattern = "vishal pandey".Replace(' ', '|');
var items = new[] { "pandey", "other", "vishal", "vishal pandey" };            
var query = items.OrderByDescending(i => Regex.Matches(i, pattern).Count);
```

UPDATE2: Custom comparer sample

```
public class ItemsComparer : IComparer<string>
{
    private string[] keywords;
    private string pattern;

    public ItemsComparer(string keywords)
    {
        this.keywords = keywords.Split();
        this.pattern = keywords.Replace(' ', '|');
    }

    public int Compare(string x, string y)
    {
        var xMatches = Regex.Matches(x, pattern).Count;
        var yMatches = Regex.Matches(y, pattern).Count;

        if (xMatches != yMatches)
            return yMatches.CompareTo(xMatches);

        if (xMatches == keywords.Length || xMatches == 0)
            return 0;

        foreach (var keyword in keywords)
        {
            var result = y.Contains(keyword).CompareTo(x.Contains(keyword));
            if (result == 0)
                continue;

            return result;
        }

        return 0;
    }
}
```

Usage:

```
var items = new[] { "pandey", "other", "vishal", "vishal pandey" };
var comparer = new ItemsComparer("vishal pandey");
Array.Sort(items, comparer);
```

Comment: Best would be doing a Match count on split of the string input then order by most matches.

Comment: @Franck agree, that will also do better sorting for items which have 2 of 3 matches. The only problem with matches is order of partial matches. E.g. `pandey` will go before `vishal` for my sample

Comment: Yes but i'm also thinking that the order might become important so a scoring system by matching position could be good to

Answer (score 2):

What I would do is to create a [custom comparer](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/8ehhxeaf(v=vs.110).aspx).
Then you create a class that implements this `IComparer<T>` interface.
In the constructor you can pass the list of expected strings.
In the compare method you can compare two instances based on how many of the expected strings the item has.